# $location.search not working if search parameters not changed

Tags: angularjs

$location.search is not reloading route if search parameter are same as parameter in current location.

if `window.location` is `"url#RouteName?param1=value1"`.

And in some button click calling method which has following code.

```
$location.path("/RouteName").search({param1 :"value1"});
```

Then Route is not getting reloaded, how to force reload. I have set `reloadOnSeach : true` in route config.

```
$routeProvider.when("RouteName", {templateurl:"pag1.html",controller:"MyCtrl",reloadOnSearch:truee});
```

Answer (score 3):

reloading the route is not done by `$location.search` explicitly, in fact it doesn't do anything if the url has not changed by the function call

use

```
$route.reload()
```

Comment: $route.reload causing controller to execute twice..? any idea.?

Comment: probably calling it wrong way, can you share the code?

Answer (score 2):

Reload will realod the route.

In case you want to change the search:

```
$location.search({'slide_id': slide_id})
```

If your route params do not change (or change to the same value) then you might need to force the location change:

```
$scope.$emit('$locationChangeSuccess');
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much for this. I had to emit the event for angular to properly update the url, and that was driving me nuts trying to figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.search` instead of `location.search`. It will work.